# How to comunicate between two array lists

Tags: arrays

I want to compare two array lists, when i press list1 items, open list2 items in new activity.please help me. i have write below code but not working. please solve my problem.**I want to compare two array lists, when i press list1 items, open list2 items in new activity.please help me. i have write below code but not working. please solve my problem.**

```js
//My String-array

<string-array name="Alphabets1">
        <item>A</item>
        <item>B</item>
        <item>C</item>
        <item>D</item>
        <item>E</item>
        <item>G</item>
        <item>H</item>
        <item>I</item>
        <item>J</item>
    </string-array>

<string-array name="Lyrics1">  
      <item>Aakaashamandunna </item>
      <item>Bangaram Adagaledu</item>
      <item>Cheyi Pattuko</item>
      <item>Devara Nee Devenalu</item>
      <item>Ella velalandu kastha</item>
      <item>Gaganamu Cheelchukoni</item>
      <item>Hallelujah Hallelujah</item>
      <item>Ide Naa Korika</item>
      <item>Janminchenu Oka Thaara</item>
      
       </string-array>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false -->
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually have a few problems to solve here. One of them is the difference between ArrayLists and arrays - I'm pretty sure you mean arrays here, since ArrayLists only hold objects, and there wouldn't be much point in forcing autoboxing and unboxing for a slower-access collection. But maybe you mean ArrayLists because you want the built-in expandability, I don't know. Something for you to determine.

I'd start with one of the sub-problems: combining two arrays or arraylists, preferring non-zero values. You'll do about the same thing with different syntax in each case.

Write a method int[] combine(int[] firstArray, int[] secondArray) to walk two arrays simultaneously and combine the values you find. You'll have to figure out what the correct behavior is when you have two non-zero values. (or are you simply summing the arrays? that'd be pretty easy)